# Присоединительные конструкции

Tags: пунктуация

"Каждый год анализируется, какое количество денег тратится на содержание школы(,) и даже на одного ученика"

Нужна ли здесь запятая? Есть ли здесь присоединительная конструкция?
Вообще, само правило о присоединит. конструкциях со словами "и даже" как-то непонятно и размыто для меня. Может, существуют более доступные разъяснения?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Каждый год анализируется, какое количество денег тратится на содержание школы  и даже на одного ученика".-Думаю, это не присоединительная конструкция, а однородные члены с частицей даже. Уберём частицу - ничего не изменится:"Каждый год анализируется, какое количество денег тратится на содержание школы и  на одного ученика". Присоединение необходимо, когда нужно что-то разъяснить, усилить значение сказанного до того, здесь ничего разъяснять не надо, всё идёт ровно. Тем более, что это явно книжная речь,может, даже деловая(отчёт), а присоединительные конструкции обычно используются в разговорной или в художественном тексте для передачи разговорной речи. О присоединении - здесь:                            http://hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-037.htm